# can't find ./mongo when i browserify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm dipping my feet in a **node** + **mongoose** + **react** + **reflux** app.

I'm also trying to create my first isomorphic app. But when i browserify the whole thing i get the following error

```
Running "browserify:client" (browserify) task
>> Error: Cannot find module './mongo' from 'project_folder/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection'
```

This problem happens the moment i require('mongoose') somewhere

I assume this is because mongoose can't work on clientside?
But i have no idea **how i should populate a (Re)Flux store?**

Here is a snippet of the store i'm defining (mongoose is already connected to mongo in another file and when i don't browserify i do get the output)

```js
var Reflux=require('reflux');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var _snippets=[];

var snippetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    data: String
});
var Snippet = mongoose.model('Snippet', snippetSchema);

var SnippetStore = Reflux.createStore({

    init: function() {
        Snippet.find(function(err, snippets) {
            _snippets = snippets;
        });
    },


    getSnippets:function() {
        return Snippet.find(function(err, snippets) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            return snippets;
        });
    }

});

module.exports=SnippetStore;
```

Comment: Yeah i thinking about going that way. But node.js is still new to me. So i should make some rest api where i do my mongoose logic. And from my store i do an Ajax call to the Api?

I found this tutorial which i'm checking out now http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/20/creating-isomorphic-apps-with-react-and-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't run mongo client side. You need to do some client-side to server-side ajax stuff.

### Passing props to the app

**Pro-tip** for isomorphic JS is to initiate the app (i.e. the top-most components) with initial props, and continue populating it client-side with flux/reflux/whatever via ajax calls to your server-side.

There are [several ways to push initial props to your app](http://www.princeton.edu/~crmarsh/react-ssr/#Syncing-Props). You let the server render the props, e.g. in a script tag (pseudo-code follows):

```
// Server-side: Put initial props on the template
<script id="reactprops">
    { JSON.stringify(initialProps) }
</script>
```

...as well as rendering the app out on the template with:

```
// Server-side: Render component
React.renderComponentToString(AppComponent(initialProps))
```

The client side should then pick up the props e.g. if you have a script tag with id `reactprops` you can get them with:

```
// Client-side: Pick up props on #reactprops
var props = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('reactprops').innerHTML);
```

... and then run the props with:

```
// Client-side: Render component
React.renderComponent(AppComponent({initialProps: props}));
```

### Passing props to the Reflux Stores

Furthermore your App needs to initiate the stores, which is easily done through `componentDidMount` in your app component. You can pass on the initial props it receives to your reflux stores like this:

```
// You need to create an action that is called when the App has mounted
var Actions = createActions(['appDidStart' /* snip-snip */]);

var App = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        Actions.appDidStart(this.props.initialProps);
    },
    render: function() { /* snip-snip */ }
});
```

Meanwhile in your stores you need to listen to the `appDidStart` action, like this:

```
var SnippetsStore = Reflux.createStore({
    init: function() {
        this.listenTo(Actions.appDidStart, this.onLoad);
    },
    onLoad: function(initialProps) {
        /* do something with initialProps */
    },
    /* snip-snip */
});
```

Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thx for providing a nice example. I started going this way. Now i created an API which gets my models and in my store i just do a call to the API instead of trying to use mongoose directly. I'll have to take a look at react-async. Only thing i'm wondering doesn't this slow things down? calling an API instead of going directly.

Comment: I know [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) has a convenience wrapper for mongodb api but I haven't tested it yet myself in a React app (if it is even possible).